# No traer los resultados si no tienen relación en Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

Estoy haciendo un motor de búsqueda de productos en Laravel. Tengo una tabla relacional con un modelo `SearchTerm` esta tabla es el que tiene el termino de busqueda (y lo hago así porque tiene un procesamiento natural del lenguaje de un algoritmo que realicé). Cada `SearchTerm` tiene un `Product` y el `Product` tiene un `Category`.

La busqueda se hace perfecto, me trae todos los registros encontrados, pero cuando quiero traerme los resultados donde el producto tenga una categoría en específico en los resultado la relacion sale `null`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Quiero que los resultados donde el producto sea nulo, no esté en la colección

Esta es la consula en el Controladoer

```
$search = SearchTerm::query();

$search->with(['product' => function($query) use ($category_id){
    $query->whereCategoryId($category_id);
}]);
$search->where('term', 'like', "%$terms%");
```

Y esta es la relación en `SearchTerm`

```
public function product(){
    return $this->belongsTo(Product::class);
}
```

Comment: este en la pregunta "Cada SearchTerm tiene un Product y el Product tiene un Category."

Comment: en resumen de todo, mira la imagen, si el product es null no deberia estar ese item en la colecion

Comment: Tendrías que [consultar la existencia de la relación](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence).

Comment: Buena bro funcionó!! te quieres ganar los puntos o respondo mi pregunta.

Comment: lo resolviste usando `whereHas`?

Comment: Si @porloscerrosΨ me aportó la documentación

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para "No traer los resultados si no tienen relación en Laravel" puedes [Consultar la existencia de relación](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence).
De esa manera para los resultados donde el modelo relacionado sea nulo (no existe), el Modelo sobre el que haces la consulta no estará incluído en la colección devuelta.

Para el caso, como tienes la condición adicional de que un campo del modelo relacionado debe corresponder con el valor de `$category_id`, puedes usar el método `whereHas` para poner condiciones `where` en tus consultas de `has`.

```
$search = SearchTerm::query();
$search->whereHas('product', function ($query) use ($category_id) {
    $query->whereCategoryId($category_id);
})->with(['product' => function($query) use ($category_id){
    $query->whereCategoryId($category_id);
}]);
```